# reduce verbose jquery if else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this jquery code that depending on which button is clicked give the variable **a** and **b** different values which then wrap a text and alert it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        "andromeda" == this.id ? (a='<‡¦>',b='</‡¦>') 
        : "milkway" == this.id ? (a='<¬>',b='</¬>') 
        : "alien-alpha" == this.id ? (a='<¬y>',b='</¬y>')
        : "galax" == this.id ? (a='<y×>',b='</y×>')
        : "grainlang" == this.id ? (a='<y×>',b='</y×>')
        ...
        : '';
        alert(a + 'put here the text to translate into our language. each one corresponds to a different alien dialect' + b);
      });
  });
```

and html

```
<button type="button" id="andromeda">‡¦</button>
<button type="button" id="milkway">¬</button>
<button type="button" id="alien-alpha">¬y</button>
<button type="button" id="galax">y×</button>
<button type="button" id="grainlang">y‡‡</button>
...
```

regarding this part, how would you cram that in as small space as possible? I have 2120 of them defined so the space taken is huge..is it possible to define a dictionary or array and smartly trasverse them as needed to reduce space?

```
"andromeda" == this.id ? (a='<‡¦>',b='</‡¦>') 
            : "milkway" == this.id ? (a='<¬>',b='</¬>') 
            : "alien-alpha" == this.id ? (a='<¬y>',b='</¬y>')
            : "galax" == this.id ? (a='<y×>',b='</y×>')
            : "grainlang" == this.id ? (a='<y×>',b='</y×>')
            ...
            : '';
```

the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jFnYx/

Comment: Why not just: http://jsfiddle.net/jFnYx/3/ ???

Comment: @A.Wolff It would be fine but there are some unconventional and different symbols at some point like at line 25 there's `<button type="button" id="sumerlang">y‡×‡</button>` which on click should enclose the text in 

`*| the text here |*`

Comment: But is there any logic behind it or you set some random characters only sometimes? If no logic, then you should instead set one and then you could refactorize your code. Or you could use a data-* attribute and use it to fill relevant content, something like what was suggested in now deleted answer below

Comment: Basically each button represents a language. On the button is represented in the original language and in the id in Latin characters. The converter (which wasn't made by me) has a fixed limit of 800 characters beginning with <*> and ending with </*> where asterisk is the language tag to be processed. To workaround this I've looked at how Markdown is structured and did something similar. The converter is smart enough to sort through that. Basically it's like I've to cram some variables as they were non-deterministic.

Comment: Will try that and come back to post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that something like this, would be helpful to save up some lines of code in the js file.

```
  $("button").click(function () {        
    var a = '<'+this.innerHTML+'>';
    var b = '</'+this.innerHTML+'>';

    alert(a + 'put here the text to translate into our language. each one corresponds to a different alien dialect' + b);
  });
```

If you want to reduce the html to. I recommended to you that generate the buttons dynamically. You can generate an array as follow:

```
var array = new Array();
array['andromeda'] = '‡¦';
array['milkway'] = '¬';
array['alien-alpha'] = '¬y';
...
```

and then iterate for generate the buttons and append it to the html.

Comment: made a compromise between your and Wolf solution but thanks :-)